# In Windows Firewall rules, what's the meaning of "System" as Program?

Tags: windows, firewall

Some of the Windows Firewall default rules refer to "System" as Program. Which are the programs identified by this?

Besides, if I create a custom rule and choose "System" as Program, would this be applied to the same set of programs?

Answer (score 0):

"System" (also shown as process ID 4) is usually how Windows represents operations done by the kernel itself, with no direct relationship to any userspace .exe process.

A few services that run within the kernel are the SMB file-sharing client and server; the Remote Desktop server (Terminal Services); and the HTTP multiplexer that is shared between IIS, WS-Management, and some other HTTP-based services.

Comment: what's the list of services that run within the kernel (as System)?

Comment: Easiest way to check on a computer is to use Process Explorer and look at all the drivers loaded by the System process. From the drivers details you get a good idea.